# Does "FiniteRingData" or something like that exists?

Tags: group-theory

I want to find a function like [`FiniteGroupData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FiniteGroupData.html?q=FiniteGroupData) but for finite rings. Does something like that exists?

Comment: Thnaks for edits!